# Socket Block Browser Connecting

Tags: python, sockets, browser, server, client

Is there any way to block access to socket from browser?
I mean i'm openning the socket on port 77321, and when im writing it to browser i'm getting request. I want to give access to socket only for my own client.

Comment: You could use authentication or some special header, if not provided close the connection.